# javascript get string before a character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string that and I am trying to extract the characters before the quote.

Example is extract the **14** from **14' - €14.99**

I am using the follwing code to acheive this.

```
$menuItem.text().match(/[^']*/)[0]
```

My problem is that if the string is something like €0.88 I wish to get an empty string returned. However I get back the full string of €0.88.

What I am I doing wrong with the match?

Comment: I don't quite understand the 'problem' you describe; if the string is equal to `€0.88` you want to get an empty string? Or if the string is `14' - €0.88` you want an empty string?

Comment: I only want a string returned if the is a quote in it. The string I wish to have returned is the characters before the quote. Again if no quote then nothing returned.

Comment: If always an int or no int, then try `var val = parseInt(str); if isNaN(val) val = ""`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is the what you should use to split:

```
string.slice(0, string.indexOf("'"));
```

And then to handle your non existant value edge case:

```
function split(str) {
 var i = str.indexOf("'");

 if(i > 0)
  return  str.slice(0, i);
 else
  return "";     
}
```

[Demo on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lechevalierd3on/PKBRw/)

Comment: Why not save the value `str.indexOf()` in a variable so you don't have to search the string twice?

Comment: Why not pass the character in  also and make this reusable?

Answer (score 6):

Nobody seems to have presented what seems to me as the safest and most obvious option that covers each of the cases the OP asked about so I thought I'd offer this:

```
function getCharsBefore(str, chr) {
    var index = str.indexOf(chr);
    if (index != -1) {
        return(str.substring(0, index));
    }
    return("");
}
```

Comment: @3on - I was just stating a reason for posting an answer after there were already a bunch of other answers.  If you like a different answer better, feel free to vote for it.  This answer was not offered at the time I posted it.  I edited my answer to change the wording.

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
str.substring(0,str.indexOf("'"));
```

Comment: Doesn't handle the case of quote not being in the string.

Comment: It does seem to work I guess - kind of an odd use of `substring()` passing `-1` to it.  I wouldn't personally feel comfortable with that illegal argument without testing in a bunch of browsers.

Comment: as a matter of fact I did test it in IE8, FF, chrome and Opera. Thats the simplest solution to the question.

Comment: You're welcome to write code that way.  I prefer to stay within the legal bounds of the argument specs, even it's a few more lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an underscore mixin in coffescript

```
_.mixin
  substrBefore : ->
    [char, str] = arguments
    return "" unless char?
    fn = (s)-> s.substr(0,s.indexOf(char)+1)
    return fn(str) if str?
    fn
```

or if you prefer raw javascript : http://jsfiddle.net/snrobot/XsuQd/

You can use this to build a partial like:

```
var beforeQuote = _.substrBefore("'");
var hasQuote = beforeQuote("14' - €0.88"); // hasQuote = "14'"
var noQoute  = beforeQuote("14 €0.88");    // noQuote =  ""
```

Or just call it directly with your string

```
var beforeQuote = _.substrBefore("'", "14' - €0.88"); // beforeQuote = "14'"
```

I purposely chose to leave the search character in the results to match its complement mixin `substrAfter` (here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/snrobot/SEAZr/ ). The later mixin was written as a utility to parse url queries. In some cases I am just using `location.search` which returns a string with the leading `?`.

Answer (score 0):

I use "split":

let string = "one-two-three";

let um = string.split('-')[0]; 
let dois = string.split('-')[1];
let tres = string.split('-')[2];

document.write(tres) //three