# Get All the numbers before a string

Tags: javascript

I was searching for a way to find the Characters before a string in JS , and I found this : [String before character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124623/javascript-get-string-before-a-character) but the page I am trying to extract information from is not exactly like this , it is more a table with each line being a name and a quantity

Example:

```
FOO     55 Thingy
BAR    105 Thingy
FOOBAR   5 Thingy
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to have the sum of all Thingy , knowing that all the `<tr>` tags are in a `<table>` given not an id but a class name.

How can I get this sum , and the number of terms in the sum ?

Comment: You can use a regular expression to find all occurrences of a number followed by "Thingy". You can learn about regular expression here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions *edit:* Seems like you are actually not working with plain text?

Comment: Is it a single string which looks like your example or is there any readable table structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to replace all spaces in line like this:

```
string = string.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
```

Then split the line and get array like this and get the second index (the number):

```
string = parseInt(string.split(' ')[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will get you the number out of these strings:

```
parseInt("FOO     55 Thingy".replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")); //return 55
parseInt("BAR    105 Thingy".replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")); //return 105
parseInt("FOOBAR   5 Thingy".replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")); //return 5
```

So if you have an array of these strings, you should be able to loop over them with this kind of regex/parseInt combo.